# Unable to extract intended portion from HTML document using symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, dom, web-scraping, goutte

I am trying to parse this section of HTML using symfony DOM crawler.

```
<div class="chunk">

<h4><img src="./handler_image.php?i=fbcaab25f6277c5e73b5ff8e5038211f" alt="Favicon" class="favicon" />
<a href="http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheNextWeb/~3/QgVH5ADY3nE/">Russia is building its own mobile OS based on Jolla’s Sailfish</a>&nbsp;<span class="footnote">18 May 2015, 6:26 pm</span>
</h4>
<img width="520" height="245" src="http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/520x245.jpg" alt="P1040853-730x547" title="Russia is building its own mobile OS based on Jolla's Sailfish" data-id="719843" />
<br />Some Description here.<br /><br />
<a href="article link">This story continues</a> at The Next Web
<div>
    <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/" border="0"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/" border="0"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/" border="0"></img>
    </a>
</div>
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
<div align="center">
    <p>
        <a href="http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/gitl.jpg" class="download"><img src="/images/mini_podcast.png" class="download" border="0" title="Download the Podcast (jpg; 0 MB)" />
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="footnote" align="center">(image/jpeg; 0 MB)</p>
</div>
<p class="footnote favicons" align="center">
    <a href="share link here!" title="Title here!"><img src="blinklist.png" alt="Blinklist" /></a>
    8 more link sharing services in same format.
</p>
```

I just want to extract this part:

```
<br />Some Description here.<br /><br />
<a href="article link">This story continues</a> at The Next Web
```

I have tried a lot of things like

```
$crawler->filter('#sp_results .chunk > div')->each(function ($node, $i) use(&$divs){
$divs[] = $node->html(); });

$crawler->filter('#sp_results .chunk .favicons')->each(function ($node, $i) use(&$footnote){
$footnote[] = $node->html();
});

$crawler->filter('#sp_results .chunk')->each(function ($node, $i) use(&$answer, &$divs, &$footnote){
$html = str_replace($footnote[$i],'',$node->html());
$html = str_replace($divs[2*$i],'',$node->html());
$html = str_replace($divs[2*$i+1],'',$node->html());
$answer[] = $html;
});
```

Is there any way to just get the portion that I mentioned above. Nothing I have wrote so far works. Either I get something extra like images and links at the bottom or I leave some portion I intend to get like link to the article.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the rule that you are using to get this "find the first `<br>` section, print that, then find the `href` immediately after"? What would you do if there were multiple `<br>` sections, or can you rely that the format of your source will not change. Good luck!